# Is there a way to get the sharepoint sites that a specific user has access too?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating an application that will allow users to scan documents on a printer and upload the document straight into Sharepoint.  I have setup the app in Azure and using administrator credentials, and I have granted access to the app to allow it read and write to Sharepoint.

The problem I am having is that when I request the list of sites in Sharepoint through the MS Graph API, I am getting a list of all the sites in the root and was wondering if there is a way that I can filter this list to being only those that are accessible to a particular user?

I can get a access token with the following code:

```
var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(appId, string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0", tenantId), redirectUri, new ClientCredential(appSecret), null, appTokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance());
var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
return authResult.AccessToken;
```

This code works OK, and I can use that access token to create a client to access graph.  I am then using the following code to get the sites:

```
var sites = await graphClient.Sites["Root"].Sites.Request().GetAsync();
```

This line also works and returns the sub-sites in Root.  But it returns all sites, so I need to somehow have this list filtered so it only returns those for whatever user is using the app.

Comment: You are using app only access token. You have to use the user access token. Check the sample here. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-microsoft-graph-api/. Refer Graph explorer for more details https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Hi Naveen, I have looked through the sample article you suggested, it looks like it is doing the same as what I am already doing, just with JavaScript rather than C#, unless I am missing something

Comment: Then you can use the PnP libraries. You can use getSubwebsForCurrentUser method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee543733(v%3Doffice.15)